# Error Installing Python.net on Python 3.7

Tags: python, .net, installation, python-3.7, python.net

I am attempting to get Python.net (pythonnet) working on Python 3.7 and when running the setup.py it fails with the following error.  I'm assuming that it has to do with a missing entry in the path lines but I coulnd't fine any reference to it.  It's basically a pretty plain install of Python 3.7 on Windows 7.  the pip install also fails with the same results.  Does anyone have a suggestion on what path or file might be missing?

```
PS C:\Users\user\pythonnet-master\pythonnet-master> python setup.py bdist_wheel
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_ext
Checking for updates from https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/.
Currently running NuGet.exe 4.6.2.
NuGet.exe is up to date.
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '15.5.180.51428' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017
\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\bin'.
All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools\geninterop\geninterop.py", line 292, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "tools\geninterop\geninterop.py", line 272, in main
    python_h = preprocess_python_headers()
  File "tools\geninterop\geninterop.py", line 192, in preprocess_python_headers
    for line in _check_output(cmd).splitlines():
  File "tools\geninterop\geninterop.py", line 41, in _check_output
    output = subprocess.check_output(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\i102604\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 376, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "C:\Users\i102604\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 453, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\i102604\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 756, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\i102604\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1155, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: There is an open issue for this: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/609

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't see it when I first looked.

Comment: install from master branch - this has been fixed now

Comment: Just wondering, do you need to install CPython first before you install Python.net?