# Unable to install pythonnet on windows 7 with python 3.7

Tags: python, .net, python-3.x, pip, python.net

I am trying to install pythonnet on windows 7 with python 3.7 using pip.

I also have installed windows sdk as suggested by

https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/wiki/Troubleshooting-on-Windows,-Linux,-and-OSX

My error logs are here: https://pastebin.com/0DLJNzQs

```
          File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Lib\subprocess
.py", line 341, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['c:\\users\\hp\\desktop\\manoj\\env
\\scripts\\python.exe', 'tools\\geninterop\\geninterop.py', 'src\\runtime\\inter
op37.cs']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Manu

Comment: you have to install from master branch of pythonnet

Comment: this is duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51310246/error-installing-python-net-on-python-3-7