# Install Python.Net in docker images (linux containers)

Tags: python, .net, docker, python.net

I'm attempting to create a simple Python script that calls a .Net function through Python.Net (http://pythonnet.github.io/).
I'm trying to configure a Docker image containing both Python, .Net and, of course, Python.net, possibly at their latest releases.

I attempted in many ways, starting from several base machines (Ubuntu, Debian, Alpine, ...).
I managed to install Python (I tried with several flavours and versions) and .Net (or Mono), but, every time I get stuck when installing Python.Net.

I get errors like those discussed in [Pip Pythonnet option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62288504/pip-pythonnet-option-single-version-externally-managed-not-recognized) or in [Error Installing Python.net on Python 3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51310246/error-installing-python-net-on-python-3-7) (suggested solutions in those posts didn't work for me).

As an example, here's a (failing!) dockerfile:

```
FROM python:slim-buster

# Install .Net  
RUN apt update
RUN apt install wget -y
RUN wget https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh
RUN chmod 777 ./dotnet-install.sh
RUN ./dotnet-install.sh -c 5.0

#install Python.Net
RUN pip install pythonnet
```

Another attempt is:

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda

# Install .Net  
RUN apt update
RUN apt install wget -y
RUN wget https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh
RUN chmod 777 ./dotnet-install.sh
RUN ./dotnet-install.sh -c 5.0

#install Python.Net

# See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61948638/1288109
RUN conda create -n myenv python=3.7
SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "myenv", "/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN conda install -c conda-forge pythonnet

ENV PATH=/root/.dotnet/:${PATH}
```

The dockerfile above builds correctly, but when running the container with a /bin/bash, issuing:

```
conda activate myenv
python myscript.py
```

I get an error like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "factorial.py", line 1, in <module>
    import clr
ImportError: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Sys' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: /opt/conda/envs/myenv/lib/../lib/libmono-native.so assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
```

(solutions found around the Internet, like https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/1034#issuecomment-626373989 didn't work, neither did attempts to use different versions of Python and .Net)

To be noted that the same error occurs also replacing .Net with Mono.

How can a docker image be built, that can run a simple Python script that makes use of Python.Net?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to C# and Docker but here are the lines from my Dockerfile that helped solve the System.DllNotFoundException in a .net7.0 project using Pythonnet and Keras.Net. I have Python:3.8 as my base and I added pythonnet via a requirements.txt. I found that suggestion [here](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/1346).

Hope that helps.

```
# Copy and install Python requirements
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Set ENV to include path for system libraries
ENV PYTHONPATH="/app"
ENV PYTHONHOME="/usr/local"
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/pythonlibs:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib:/lib/x86_64-linux- 
gnu/'
```